# VCL UI component to draw a line and divide it in "clickable segments"?

Tags: delphi, 2d, delphi-xe2

I am analysing an application to be done ideally in Delphi (since i will use many libraries I aldrady have), but the only reason that prevents me from finalizing the Delphi choice is that i didn't find a graphical UI component I need.

The customer wants to draw lines and divide them.

Let me tell you the scenario:

1) lines are 2D representation of the "external layer" of a skycraper made basically of frames + glass windows.

2) user wants to draw the line (= "the wall") and then say "divide this in 6 windows", so i want that my line becomes made of 6 small clickable segments, so the user can click on them and edit properties of the selected window (the skycraper's window).

I don't want to do this with low level usage of TLine, is it there some intermediate component you know to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: AutoCAD building design suite?  It's cheaper than two programmers for a month-long project... especially if you don't already know how to divide a line into segments.  Otherwise, what you are asking for is a pretty specialized behaviour and is going to be something you will have to implement with some form of simple line.

Comment: @J... you mean to use a commercial software (http://www.autodesk.com/suites/autocad-design-suite/overview). It is a good suggesion, anyway my customer wants more features, not only the capability to draw lines, this is why i need an application written by me. So it looks like th only way is to Inherit from TLine and add features...

Comment: If AutoCAD doesn't have enough features for you, you might explore the possibility of developing a plugin.  There are APIs available and you'll likely end up with a much better solution in less time for less money than trying to rebuild something like that from the ground up.  When you're talking about skyscrapers it's probably best to start with a professional tool anyway...it sounds like the sort of thing there's some budget for.

Comment: @J... I agree with you, I will keep in mind your suggestion in case the customer insists on a CADlike interface. For sure customer has money, skycrapers are not fried eggs, anyway the software they need is an "after construction" mainteanance tool, so the CADdish interface is too much in my opionion. And moreover APIs sound nice, but when you start fighting with them there are always R&D surprises, this is my eperience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decide to use [TMS Diagram Studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/diagram.asp), since I already own this component and let the user draw the external walls. Once the walls have been drawn I will start a guided procdure that will allow the user to input some wall properties (like "number of windows", ...) and then I will delete the line and recreate many lines, one per window, using X, Y coordinates of the original row and I will basically creatae many line onjects at design time to have clickable elements. I don't need in this way to code a complex component. This is a workaroundbut my customer agreed on this, mostly because in this way I can offer my work for a lower cost...